# What will happen if I transfer large sums of money into my bank account from a pre-paid debit card or gift card?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, banking, irs, money-transfer

I want to use my credit card to put money on a pre-paid debit card, transfer it to my bank account, and pay off the credit card with that money so I can get points.

I read that transferring more than $10k into your bank account in less than a year like this can raise red flags.

What should I expect?

Comment: I think you'll find that loading a prepaid card with funds from your credit card will not provide "points". They thought of that already.

Comment: Buying gift cards (at grocery stores, pharmacy, etc) will still give you points, even the Visa/Mastercard/Amex branded cards.

Comment: I doubt it will work. Those programs usually have stipulations to prevent that exact behavior. Usually you are required to carry a balance for certain amount of time in order to get the points. Check your user agreement before you do anything.

Comment: Is a pre-paid debit card that you can get cash off of a thing?  I've never seen something like that but maybe I just haven't looked.  My experience has always been that once money is on a card (gift card, pre-paid Visa, etc), it stays there until spent.

Comment: It's not hard to get points or cash back for buying prepaid cards. The tricky part, as far as I am aware, is getting the prepaid cards back into a bank account.

Comment: @stannius You can tie the prepaid card to a paypal account and send all the money to another paypal account (for a non-trivial fee).  The money can then be transferred to a bank account (for 1% fee if you want it within a half hour, for free if you can wait a day or two).

Comment: Usually prepaid visa cards and such have a purchase value associated with them that is more expensive than rewards would provide. e.g. A $100 one through Amazon costs $105.95, so unless you have close to 6% in rewards, it wouldn't be profitable.

Comment: @Xrylite that's a little high... you can probably get cards at a grocery store for $4.95 fee, up to $500 value, so effectively 1%. Converting it by paypal would cost more, about 3%. A 4% reward would be the break-even point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Cash. The $10K law is for literal cash. An envelope of $100 bills, or bag of smaller denominations. Not movements of money, the kind that occur all the time. I am retired, and make regular transfers of over $10K. Direct transfers from broker (IRA/401(k)) to my local bank. No red flags.

That said, try your plan for one small cycle and let us know how it goes. The prepaid cards come with a fee, typically $5, which is 1% of the $500 gift card. But, the next step, getting the money back off, is also not frictionless. You can't easily just turn the card back to cash to deposit.

You are on the right track to maximize card points, however. If/when you see a deal which offers a bonus or large cash back on Pharmacy or Grocery stores, this may be the path to take. But you'll be left with a stack of these cards to use for your natural purchases for the next months.

(Anecdotally, some time ago, a bank offered a credit card with a 90 day period of "10% cash back on grocery store/pharmacy purchases". I purchased $50K worth of gift cards, 100 cards with a value of $500 each, and got $5000 cash back for doing so. There was a $5 fee per card, for a total $500 cost of the transaction.

We then used the cards over about 18 months for normal spending. By the time I exceeded $30K, the bank pulled the offer. No new customers would get this deal. But still honored their 90 days with me.)

Comment: There's a card doing a 10% back at grocery stores promotion in Canada right now, but they limit it to $2000 spent, so $200 back. They've probably heard of you.

Comment: "No new customers would get this deal", this is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on your last paragraph. "I purchased $50K worth of gift cards, at a cost of $500 ($5 ea) and got $5000 cash back for doing so." It makes sense that you got 5000$ back, for the cash back, but what I don't understand is the 50k worth of gift cards at 500$ / 5$ each?

Comment: The fee per card was $5. So I lost $500 in the purchase, but got $5000 in reward/ cash back. (I just edited to clarity.)

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer it would help clarify the anecdote a little further if you stated you got 100 gift cards of $500 each (if I mathed correctly).

Comment: updated if anyone would like to re-read.

Comment: MBN to have a limit on a new card to be able to purchase $50k of gift cards.

Comment: @xyious - while it’s good to be me, the limit was only $10K. I made frequent payments, buying $4-6K worth of cards and then making a payment.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Just don't let it look like you're [structuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring).

The $10,000/year thing isn't that.   The $10,000 is **per transaction**.  There's no "per year" requirement, but there is an "over a period of time" thing **because of [structuring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuring)**. Structuring is when you evade the $10,000 limit by breaking a large deposit into a series of smaller deposits, say five deposits of $8000 each made on 5 days.

So the banks and Feds care about patterns of deposits that look like structuring. If your deposits are far apart, say every 2-6 weeks and of varying amounts, that won't raise any red flags.   If you deposit between $2000 and $8000 every day for years, under the business name A1A Car Wash, they're not going to care about that, it's obviously a business.

That said, the government is on the watch for other ways to launder money; i.e. Convert cash into deposited funds without drawing notice to oneselves.  **If you could have also bought those gift cards for cash, then it will appear to banks as if you *did* buy them for cash and are now laundering**.  They will not know that you did not pay cash and did charge them on a credit card.

However, they will not care if the amounts of money fall substantially under $10,000 over a several-month period. Nobody cares about money laundering at such a small scale; there would be 1000 other ways to do that.  E.g. Just pay your rent with cash.

Comment: For a car wash to make $8000 every day it either needs to be very busy or have a 99.1% chemically pure cleaning agent.

Comment: @Paulpro It depends on how many branches the car wash has.

Comment: Related, when I worked as a cashier at Home Depot, there was a story about a guy, who upon hearing that his drawer could be off by up to $5 without consequences, pocketed $4.95 out of it every day (hourly pay was about $8). He got fired in a hurry.

Comment: @glglgl That was a subtle Breaking Bad reference, to match the one in my answer.

Comment: I just want to point out that the act of breaking your deposits into smaller deposits to avoid the reporting limit is called structuring, not smurfing. Smurfing is a form of structuring, but refers to getting other people to deposit the money for you.

Comment: @CHenry thanks, did not know that.

Comment: @Harper That's something I only know by name. Should change that one day.

Comment: Structuring is illegal even if the money was legally obtained. In today's climate of civil asset forfeiture, you could find yourself charged with a crime, and with your money confiscated, all because you believed an incorrect myth about the max allowed deposit.